# android java/kotlin recyclerview items not visible

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

i am trying to build an app that scans for bluetooth devices and displays them in a recyclerview. i am writing some of the app using java and some of the app in kotlin. for some reason my recyclerview items aren't visible. somebody please help me to find what mistake that i am making. i am posting the code for my activity and also my recycler view. To clarify my question. The discovery succeeds, devices are found, and all the inherited methods in my adapter seem to be called. I placed log messages in them and I still see nothing in the recyclerview. Why is nothing show up? here is my activity written in java :

```
public class ToofActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

private static final String TAG = "ToofActivity";
private static final int REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 222;

private static BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;

private TextView mStatusLabel;
private Switch mStatusSwitch;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private RecyclerView mDeviceRecylcer;
private static ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mDevices = new ArrayList<>();
private DeviceAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_toof);

    checkLocationPermission();

    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    mStatusLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_view);
    mStatusLabel.setText(btAdapter.isEnabled() ? "Active" : "Inactive");
    mStatusSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.status_switch);
    mStatusSwitch.setChecked(btAdapter.isEnabled());
    mStatusSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.search_progress_bar);
    mDeviceRecylcer = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.device_recycler);

    mDeviceRecylcer.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mAdapter = new DeviceAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    mDeviceRecylcer.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.searchOption:
            DiscoveryTask discovery = new DiscoveryTask(btAdapter, this, mProgressBar);
            discovery.setOnCompleteListener(new DiscoveryTask.OnCompletedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    mAdapter.updateItems(mDevices);
                }
            });
            discovery.execute((Void) null);
            break;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
        btAdapter.enable();
        mStatusLabel.setText("Active");
    } else {
        btAdapter.disable();
        mStatusLabel.setText("Inactive");
    }
}

public static void setDeviceList(ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> deviceList) {
    mDevices.clear();
    mDevices = deviceList;
}

protected void checkLocationPermission() {
    if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION: {
            if (grantResults.length <= 0
                    || grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                checkLocationPermission();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

and here is the code for my recyclerview written in kotlin :

```
class DeviceAdapter(val mContext : Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DeviceAdapter.DeviceHolder>(){

val mDevices = ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>()

fun updateItems(list: ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>){
    mDevices.clear()
    mDevices.addAll(list)
    Log.d(TAG, "updating items : $mDevices")
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DeviceHolder, position: Int) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder called!")
    holder.bindItems(mDevices.get(position))
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): DeviceHolder{
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder called!")
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.device_item, parent, false)
    return DeviceHolder(v)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return mDevices.size
}

inner class DeviceHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        val nameView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameView) as TextView
        val addrView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addressView) as TextView

    fun bindItems(btDevice: BluetoothDevice){
        Log.d(TAG, "holder created!")
        nameView.text = btDevice.name
        addrView.text = btDevice.address
    }
}

companion object {
    val TAG = "DeviceAdapter"
}

}
```

thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was the context that i was using. my context was the one returned from `getApplicationContext()` which was incorrect. now i have changed it to just using `this`. once making that change it all viewholder items were visible.

Answer (score 1):

you can remove context in contractor adapter and can replace this line using context inside adapter  `val v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.device_item, parent, false)` into  `val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.device_item, parent, false)` or if you want context inside adapter as argument replace this statement

```
 mAdapter = new DeviceAdapter(getApplicationContext());
```

to  `mAdapter = new DeviceAdapter(this);`